# Updating multiple rows with select option

Tags: php, mysql

Database:

```
+------+------+
|  id  |status|
+------+------+
|  50  |   2  |
+------+------+
|  51  |   0  |
+------+------+
|  52  |   1  |
+------+------+
```

As you can see there is a column named id and another column named status which indicates the current status of sth (2=done, 1=in work, 0 = open)

So I have done a little GUI where you can choose the current status through an select option input field, it also preselects the current record for status.

```
function generateSelect($name = '', $options = array(), $default = '') {
    $html = '<select name="'.$name.'">';
    foreach ($options as $option => $value) {
        if ($value == $default) {
            $html .= '<option value='.$value.' selected="selected">'.$option.'</option>';
        } else {
            $html .= '<option value='.$value.'>'.$option.'</option>';
        }
    }

    $html .= '</select>';
    return $html;
}
```

As I have mentioned each number in the database stands for a text with its status

```
$statusArray=array("Done" => "2", "In Work" => "1","Open" => "0");
```

This is what the generation of all the select option fields for every id looks like:

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

            $strStatus = generateSelect("stat", $statusArray, $row['status']);             

        echo '<tr><td>' . $row['id']. '</td><td>'.$strStatus.'</td></tr>';
```

What I am trying to do right now is that when the submit button is pressed it updates all status records.

What I have tried:

1.getting the selected one

```
function getSelected(){

    $value="";

    if($_POST['status']=="0")
        $value="0";
    else if($_POST['status']=="1")
        $value="1";
    else if($_POST['status']=="2")
        $value="2";
    else if($_POST['status']=="3")
        $value="3";

    return $value;
```

}
2. SQL statement where probably the problem is

```
$tmp = getSelected();
$sql = "UPDATE form SET status='$tmp' WHERE *";
```

Another option would be just saving the one edited, maybe with the onchange method from the select field?
Really appreciate every help I can get :) ty in advance for taking time to look throught the code.

**UPDATE**

ty for the quick answer and Extra Update @MarioZ

However it still doesnt seem rly to work. :/ maybe you can help me out there ^^

first worked fine with just $row['id'] because I want to be able to update more fields i have added ."['status']"

```
 $strStatus = generateSelect($row['id']."['status']", $statusArray, $row['status']);
```

and also tried this for person, with no success then.

```
$personArray=array("Zivildiener" => "4", "Schmikl" => "3", "Poier" => "2","Dirnb&ouml;ck" => "1","Tom" => "0");

$strPerson = generateSelect($row['id']."['person']", $personArray, $row['person']);
```

and I have also added this which also worked fine, however only for status :/

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {

    $sql = "UPDATE form SET status='$value' WHERE id = $key";

    $result = $conn->query($sql); }
```

Idk I honestly didnt really understand the foreach loop, but it worked somehow, you maybe need to know that there are more columns in the database which I didnt listen, but despite all this the first answer you gave worked perfectly, no clue how though :x so I would really appreciate your help again if you have some time :)

Comment: If you want to update the three rows you need to post the id of each with the status. Isn't it what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the id of each row as the name of each select:

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

            $strStatus = generateSelect($row['id'], $statusArray, $row['status']);             

        echo '<tr><td>' . $row['id']. '</td><td>'.$strStatus.'</td></tr>';
```

So, when you retrieve the $_POST data you have the id as key and the value of the option as value:

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $sql = "UPDATE form SET status='$value' WHERE id = $key";
}
```

You can adapt your function `getSelected()` in that loop to ge sure no other value is injected in the query.

**FINAL UPDATE:**

This is a way to do what you want to do, I've wrote to be easy to understand and apply to your code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form name="tasks" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
<?php
// Names of fields
$status_list[] = "open";
$status_list[] = "in work";
$status_list[] = "done";

$person_list[] = "John";
$person_list[] = "Bran";
$person_list[] = "Edd";

$task_list[50] = "Kill enemies";
$task_list[51] = "Avenge father";
$task_list[52] = "Sleep";
// Database conection
$db = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "test");
// Update database only if post
if(!empty($_POST)) {
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
    if($db->query("UPDATE change_status SET status = {$value['status']}, person = {$value['person']} WHERE id = $key ")) {
            echo "<span>".$key." - UPDATED!</span>";
        } else {
            echo "<span>".$key." - FAILED!</span>";
        }
    }
}
// Get database
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM change_status");
// Draw the HTML content
$form = "";
while($result = $query->fetch_array()) {
    $form .= '<div>';
    $form .= '<span>'.$task_list[$result['id']].'</span>';
    $form .= ' - ';
    $form .= '<select name="'.$result['id'].'[status]">';
    foreach($status_list as $key => $value) {
        $form .= '<option value="'.$key.'"';
        $form .= $result['status'] == $key? " selected" : "";
        $form .= '>'.$value.'</option>';
    }
    $form .= '</select>';

    $form .= '<select name="'.$result['id'].'[person]">';
    foreach($person_list as $key => $value) {
        $form .= '<option value="'.$key.'"';
        $form .= $result['person'] == $key? " selected" : "";
        $form .= '>'.$value.'</option>';
    }
    $form .= '</select></div>';
}

echo $form; // display html content
?>

<input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ty mate :) this works wonderful, could you help me out one more time pls :) what would I need to do if I had a second column named person, i obviosuly cant just do $strPerson = generateSelect($row['id'], $personArray, $row['person']), since there would be select input fields with same id. Maybe you have a solution for this problem too ^^ and ty a lot so far :)

Comment: No problem @AndroidAmateur99 I have updated the answer with a guideline to do what you need. Hope it helps! And remember to click 'accept the answer' if it works.

Comment: hey :) wanted to say ty for your help, but there is still a little problem ^^ have made an update on what I have tried so far, would be nice if you could look through the update :)

Comment: There you are @AndroidAmateur99 you can try it and change it as you need. I wrote it plain and easy to understand.